# How to re-prompt a component after certain amount of days in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a component that asks the user for certain app permissions. This component prompts the user to either accept the permissions or click "Later". If the user clicks later, I would like to have the component re-prompt after a certain number of days, the number of days being after 1 day, after 3, after 7, after 14, and after 30.

What I have currently:
I have a useEffect() that when a page initially loads it would show the component based on a flag (`permissionsEnabled`). The flag checks to see if notifications have been enabled.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (!permissionsEnabled) {
  navigateTo(permissionComponent)
} }, []);
```

I initially thought to store the DateTime when the user clicks "Later" and then compare that datetime when a user logins and check if the difference in dates matches the days (after 1 day, 3, 7, 14, 30) and re-prompt the component as such. But I later realized that if the user clicks "Later" again the stored datetime would update and the difference between the login date and the new "Later" date would always be 1 day. So the component would be re-prompted every other day.

How do I update the `permissionComponent` flag and re-prompt the component by comparing the stored dates to re-prompt after 1, 3, 7, 14, and 30 days?

Comment: You need to store the date to the device's AsyncStorage, though it sounds like you're already doing that?

Comment: Hey chrisans, just wondering if my answer was of help to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store 2 values, the last day the user put off the acceptance of permissions and the number of days for the next try, and check if the current date is equal to the last try + amount of days to show the modal again. If the user clicks `later` again you update the last try date with the current date and the number of days for the next try depending on the current value

```
//global constant
const DAYS_FOR_NEXT_TRY = {
  0: 1,
  1: 3,
  3: 7,
  7: 14,
  14: 30,
  30: 30,
};

...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!permissionsEnabled) {
      const lastTryDate = /* get from local storage */
      const lastDaysForNextTry = /* get from local storage */

      // values are null, it is the firs time
      if (!lastTryDate || !lastDaysForNextTry) {
        navigateTo(permissionComponent);
        return;
      }

      const lastTryTodayDiff = /*calculate diff between lastTrydate and today */

      // we haven't show the permission modal for more than permitted days
      if (lastTryTodayDiff >= lastDaysForNextTry) {
        navigateTo(permissionComponent);
      }
    }
  }, []);
...
```

and in the `Later` button onPress event

```
      const lastTryDate = /* get from local storage */
      const lastDaysForNextTry = /* get from local storage */
      AsyncStorage.setItem(
        'lastTryDate',
        new Date()
      );
      AsyncStorage.setItem(
        'lastDaysForNextTry',
        DAYS_FOR_NEXT_TRY[lastDaysForNextTry || 0]
      );
```